# The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь скомпилировать [проект](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot), который требует наличие библиотеки dnlib. 
Сама библиотека в References указана, Framework'и проекта и библиотеки совпадают (.NET Framework 2.0), однако при компиляции происходит ошибка

> The type or namespace name 'dnlib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

на строку `using dnlib.DotNet;`

Если же открыть библиотеку через Object Inspector, то пространство имен dnlib.DotNet там можно увидеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я дурак?

Comment: а где проект de4dot.blocks? какие у него референсы?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
У вас большое количество ошибок и не факт, что эта ошибка является первой. Посмотрите какая ошибка фигурирует первой в окне Output при построении проекта. Вполне возможно, что у вас нет прав на копирование библиотеки в целевую папку или еще какие-то проблемы.

Comment: большое количество ошибок ни о чем не говорит, это могут быть те же самые попытки использования классов из проекта, который не скомпилировался